# How to remove widget only for Oreo and higher?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-jobscheduler

I see that the management of widgets changed with Android (use of the new JobScheduler).

I don't want to propose anymore my widget on Android 8 and higher but still want to propose it on lower versions.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by disabling a component of widget. But it still be available in widget list of launcher on first install, but will be removed from this list as soon as you disable it programatically. One of the way is to disable it on application onCreate() or something like that.

So all that you need:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   PackageManager pm  = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
   ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.app",".widget.myCoolWidget");
   pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```